# Why are my Parse API requests increasing rapidly each day?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have an app that I am making and I'm using Parse as my server. When I log into parse.com and go to my apps I can see that my app has 21k requests. I am the only one using/testing the app, and I can not imagine that its me sending all of those! Can anyone explain why the app would receive so many requests? Some days it sends out over 3k requests.

Any help would be great!

Comment: maybe some loop is running unexpectedly making requests without you realising?

Comment: There is no way to tell what's wrong without seeing the code. I'd suggest putting a log statement in every place where you send a request to parse. May be even implement a counter, so you can track exactly how many requests are made during your testing, and then compare the results to parse.com.